# How to know the number of models found by Alloy Analyzer?

Tags: alloy, formal-verification, formal-methods

Is there a way to know how many output models Alloy Analyzer finds?

I need to know how changing the alloy model changes the number of Alloy instances found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you run the analysis on a model, the tool only generate the first instance.
The next instances are generated on the fly as your browse them. So I'd say that, limiting oneself on using the GUI of the tool, there's no way to know how many instances are found by the analyzer except by reviewing them manually.

I believe however that it shouldn't be too hard to write a small java program that calls the Alloy API to generate an instance (A4Solution), and count how many time [next()](http://alloytools.org/documentation/alloy-api/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4compiler/translator/A4Solution.html#next()) can be called before no more instances are returned ...